# Get value after the keys in xslt 2.0

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

Consider my XML:

```
<Data>/Keys1/ABCD/keys4/KLDS111/keys2/88888/keys5//ID/34234/keys5/Sample</Data>
```

I need to get the value after each keys. The keys can be in any order, here are the keys that I need to check:

- /keys1/
- /keys2/
- /keys4/
- /keys5//ID/
- /keys5/

**My expected output:**

```
<Data>
  <DGH_hdj>ABCD</DGH_hdj>
  <hdu_pd>
    <hdu>KLDS111</hdu>
    <ydhf>88888</ydhf>
  </hdu_pd>
  <oOo>34234</oOo>
  <pio>Sample</pio>
</Data>
```

In my example file, I need to get the value in between each keys. I am thinking 
of using an array and get the index of each keys. But, the problem is that I don't
know how will I apply that logic since I am still not familiar in XSLT.

Your feedback is much appreciated.

Comment: Your approach is, I think, the good one; just note that in XSLT arrays are called sequences. First, tokenize your string [as Michael showed you](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45796335), store it in a sequence and retrieve the keys using regex.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you can extract the value of `keys2`:

```
<xsl:template match="Data">
    <xsl:variable name="t" select="tokenize(., '/')" />
    <result>
        <xsl:value-of select="$t[index-of($t, 'keys2') + 1]"/>
    </result> 
</xsl:template>
```

Demo: http://xsltransform.net/jxDigUw

---

P.S. Note that XML is case-sensitive.